# can we create a pick list in lead page layout getting data from external api

Tags: salesforce, apex

I am trying to call an external api from salesforce apex class which will get all the products.so next i want to show these products as picklist in salesforce lead creation or edit page.I am not sure its possible or not.Any solution or workaround on these is mostly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this on a standard layout.
I personnaly could do this in a Visualforce page. Probably you probably can do this in a Lightning page as well.

Comment: can you please provide any code sample.So my doubt in this case is can we pass data from visual force page  that is opening like a pop up window to our parent window(which is lead edit page).

Comment: My case is rather a 'monolithic' programmation, i.e. list boxes are on the VF page and I manage the content from Apex controller. What you describe is more sophisticated and I don't see a way to do this with a standard layout. There is no standard/supported way to open a pop-up from Salesforce but you can do it using a JavaScript override of the standard function used for that (more details here: https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/). But again, you need to use a custom VF page replacing the standard layout to get to it.